# Add/Remove users to an array of ObjectId Fails

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose, mongoose-schema

Thank you for taking out time to read this.
**I have two models `positions` and `users`. I'm trying to add 'users' to the Array of 'Recruiters' as seen below in positions Model.** When I make the put request, Everything goes well but my amended array which includes the new userids fail to save and give the following error.

> 'Cast to [ObjectId] failed for value "[3]" at path "recruiters"'

**PositionsModel.js**

```
 const positionsSchema = new Schema(
      {
          title: {
              type: String,
              required: [true, 'Position title is required'],
          },
          description: {
              type: String
          },
          recruiters: [{
              type: Schema.Types.ObjectId,
              ref: "users"
          }]
      },
      { timestamps: true }
  );
```

**usersModel.js**

```
const usersSchema = new Schema(
    {
        name: {
            type: String,
            required: [true, "Name must be provided"],
        },
        email: {
            type: String
        },
        password: {
            type: String,
        }
    },
    { timestamps: true }
);
```

**Controller.js (Problem Here)**
I'm making a put request to add recruiter to the Array in Positions Model and sending two parameters. Id (this is the position id) and Recruiter (this is the userId)

```
exports.addRemove = async (req, res, next) => {
    try {
        const {id, recruiter} = req.params;
        
        //Get Current Position Details
        const position = await positionsModel.findById(id)

             
        // Update Position  
        const newList = position.recruiters.push(recruiter) //this works, It adds the id to array
        const newData = {
            recruiters: newList
        }
        
        //At this point if you console log position.recruiters. You will see the newly added item in the array
            
        const uptPosition = await positionsModel
        .findByIdAndUpdate(id, newData, {
            new: true,
            runValidators: true,
        })
        .exec(); // this fails with error

        if(!uptPosition) {
            return res.status(400).json("Position failed to update");
        }

        //Success Response
        return  res.status(200).json('Position Updated');
        
        
    } catch (err) {
        console.log({ Error: err.message });
        return;
    }
```

**Current List of Recruiter Id's in the array**
[image: a busy cat]

**The Current Recruiter Array already has two userIds. The third one gets added successfully to the `newList` variable, but it doesn't get saved in the database. You can see the error below as it points to the third element that was just added in the controller**

> 'Cast to [ObjectId] failed for value "[3]" at path "recruiters"'

Comment: convert this is `recruiter` id to object id type before push using ,`mongoose.Types.ObjectId(recruiter)`

Comment: I tried that didn't really help. I ended up changing the code to solve this. It's best to use mongoose $Push and $Pull query to add/remove an array of ObjectId's.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> The `push()` method adds one or more elements to the end of an array and returns the new length of the array.

You did:

```
const newList = position.recruiters.push(recruiter);
```

Then `newList` will be the new length of recruiters array(in your case is 3). You can fix this by changing your code to:

```
position.recruiters.push(recruiter);
position.markModified('recruiters'); // mark recruiters as having pending change
position.save();
```